# Solr search query by Datetime.Year

Tags: solr, content-search

I configured Solr index to the path where I created some articles using templates, templates have the same fields with data type as in below model

```
<Root>/sitecore/content/Articles</Root>
```

My model looks like this

```
public class Article : SearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("_uniqueid")]
    public string ItemPath { get; set; }

    [IndexField("_group")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [IndexField("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [IndexField("publisheddate")]
    public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }

    [IndexField("summary")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

}
```

When I query I can get the list of articles and I can read correct PublishedDate, but when I extend my query where I want articles in a year

```
list.Where(c => c.PublishedDate.Year == 2017).ToList();
```

It returns zero rows

Comment: I imagine (while sloppy) you could query based on a date range instead, i.e. 01/01/2017 to 12/31/2017. Looking at a previous project, I see we got the entire result set, then filtered by year after-the-fact. But curious about a pure Solr solution.

Comment: I have to filter by different parameters,like in year, in month, in month of year etc. it will lead to ugly code practice, i was also expecting may be with Sitecore9/Solr this time its improved, or if there is some extension work around

Comment: You can always create computed fields specifically for Year/Month. That will make your query clean.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach, can you please give me an example how should i configure it in index configurations and do i need to create such field in template as well? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @jrap in the comments, you can use computed fields to solve this.

To use computed field, you would need to

1) Create a class that contains the logic to generate/calculate your new computed field

```
public class ComputedYearField: IComputedIndexField

{
 public string FieldName { get; set; }
 public string ReturnType { get; set; }

 public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable) {

  Item item = (indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem);

  if (item != null)
  {

   // check if item is an Article
   if(item.TemplateID == "YOURARTICLETEMPLATEID")
   {
    // extract the year from PublishDate field 
    var dateField = (DateField)item.Fields["PublishedDate"];
    var itemDate = Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime(dateField.Value);

    return itemDate.Year
   }
  }
  return null;
 }

}
```

2) Patch your Sitecore Solr(or lucene) settings so that the computed field will be run during indexing.

```
<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
<field fieldName="ComputedYear" returnType="int">
     MyProjectNamespace.ComputedYearField,MyProjectNamespace
</field>
</fields>
```

3) Run reindex of your Sitecore indexes. Then you would be able to use your computed field

```
list.Where(c => c.ComputedYear == 2017).ToList();
```

You can find more details on computed fields in this [blogpost](https://adarshbh.wordpress.com/2017/07/03/sitecore-indexing-creating-computed-fields/)

PS: I have not tested the code above

Comment: To wrap it up, the OP would also need: `[IndexField("ComputedYear")]
    public int ComputedYear { get; set; }` added to `Article`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to query against Date field you should compare with **Datetime** type.

date.Year, date.Month etc. don`t work with date field queries.

Rewrite your query like this:

```
var dateStart = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
var dateEnd = new DateTime(year, 12, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year,12));

list.Where(x => x.Date.Between(dateStart, dateEnd, Inclusion.Both));
// or
// list.Where(x => x.Date>=dateStart && x.Date<=dateEnd);
```

Comment: I tried the above but it does not compares with date at all, what could be the reason? for example to made it simple i tried `list.Where(x => x.Date < Datetime.Today).ToList()` still returns all rows

Comment: How your field looks in solr, like: "publisheddate_tdt":"2019-04-11T21:00:00Z" ?

Comment: `"publisheddate_tdt":"2019-04-21T06:00:00Z"` exactly copied from Solr, and on Sitecore template its data type is Datetime

Comment: Hmm.. It should work OOTB if you your field is general field (not computed field). If computed - just be sure that is has returnType="datetime"

Comment: By rebuilding index i was able to query  by date, BTW i was not able to find Date.Between method on date, am i missing some library to add? thanks